# React JSX timer reset on button click

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

An initial time limit is grabbed as part of the fetched response object. It is then set after questions are also set.

The issue is when clicking an answer the timer resets. Maybe the executed fetch loop is continuously running causing the timer to be reset? Though i am unsure if it is and how to prevent this from occurring.

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import Countdown from "react-countdown";

export default function Quiz() {

  var passedid = 1; //replace this in future
  const [quiz, setQuiz ]=useState('')
  const [executedFetch, setExecutedFetch]=useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${window.ipAddress.ip}/Quiz/${passedid}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => { 
      // console.log(json)
      setQuiz(json)
      setExecutedFetch(true)
     })
  },[]) 

  const [questionList, setQuestionList]=useState([])
  const [executedSet, setExecutedSet]=useState('')
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);

  const [timeLimit, setTimeLimit] = useState('');
  const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (executedFetch){
      setQuestionList(quiz.questions)
      setTimeLimit((quiz.timeLimit * 1000) + Date.now())
      setStartTime(Date.now())
      setExecutedSet(true)
    }
  })

  const Completionist = () => <span>Time has run out!</span>;
  const renderer = ({ hours, minutes, seconds, completed }) => {
    if (completed) { return <Completionist />; }  // Render completed state
    else { return <span>{hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}</span>; } // Render countdown
  };

    const [result, setResult] = useState(0);
    const [showResult, setShowResult] = useState(false);

  const handleAnswerButton = (correct, startTime, timeLimit) => {

    if (Date.now() >= (timeLimit) ){
      console.log("no time left")
      setShowResult(true);
    }
  
    else{
      if (correct) { setResult(result + 1); }
      const next = current + 1;
  
      if (next < questionList.length) 
      {     
        setCurrent(next);  
      } 
      else{
        console.log("time left but done")
        setShowResult(true);
      }
      
    }

    };

    if (executedSet){
        return (
            <div className='app'>
        <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/>
        <Countdown date={timeLimit}>
            <Completionist />
        </Countdown>
        
        {showResult ? (
          <div className='result'>
            Your result is {result} of {questionList.length}
          </div>
        ) : (
          <>
            <div className='question'>
              <div className='index'>
                <span>Question {current + 1}</span>/{questionList.length}
              </div>
              <div className='text' onCopy={handleCopy} >{questionList[current].question}</div>
            </div>

            <div className='answer-section'>
              {questionList[current].answers.map((answer, index) => (
                <button key={answer.id} onClick={()=> handleAnswerButton(answer.correct, startTime, timeLimit)}>{answer.content}</button>
              ))}
            </div>
          </>
        )}

            </div>
        );
    }

    else {
        return (
            <div className='app'>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: The effect that sets executed fetch will only run once since you have passed an empty array as the second argument. The effect that depends on the executedFetch however will run multiple times I think. You should pass a second argument as follows:  `useEffect(()=>{...}, [executedFetch]);` to it and try.

Comment: okay, I get your point on making it dependent to the executedfetch however the executed fetch loop should only be running once also, Meaning i could move everything inside the initial get loop, though is there an alternate method to prevent multiple execution? @BlackWind

Comment: Actually no. In this piece of code, you need `executedFetch` to be present and then based on when its a valid value, you need to set the question list, time limit etc and other values. So, you DO need the second `useEffect`. You just don't need it to run every time an update happens to the state. From what I can see, I think once `executedFetch` is set, this effect will keep running over and over again since you didn't put a condition for it to stop. Try the effect with `executedFetch` as the condition. You should get the thing working. @ABpositive